# SQL Get all records from table 1 based on criteria 2 if part of result of Query 1 Criteria 1 (Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to do an operation on one table where I run an initial Query(Query1) which pulls data from Table 1 based on a condition. This Subquery is then used against Table 1 to get all records in Query 1 plus all Records in Table 1 which match a second criteria.

This is because I have many records per individual in Table 1 and I need all of them as long as one record matches the criteria from Query 1. I have tried many different queries to no avail. The closest I have thus far is:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM 
Table1 A
INNER JOIN Query1 B on A.[ID] = B.[ID]
```

And Query1 looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
WHERE [Last Updated Date] >=#4/1/2018 4:00:00 AM# 
And [Last Updated Date] <=#5/1/2018 4:00:00 AM#
```

The end result I want is something like

Table 1

```
ID  Last Updated
1   1-Jan-18
2   6-May-18
2   3-Jan-18
2   5-Apr-18
3   6-Apr-18
4   5-May-18
```

Query Result:

```
ID  Last Updated
2   6-May-18
2   3-Jan-18
2   5-Apr-18
3   6-Apr-18
```

The query I wrote gives errors and I end up with over 3x the total records so clearly something is going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here's a small hint, don't query a table and then `INNER JOIN` that table to that same query. Just create a new query that gets what you need. That is the reason for the doubling, etc. But the question arises, what exactly are you trying to do with the `INNER JOIN` you are doing, because based on what you wrote in the SQL in the **best case** scenario, it would be no different from the Query itself (assuming no duplication). Your end result is not possible, based on the date restrictions from the query in use.

Comment: *plus all Records in Table 1 which match a second criteria* ... what second criteria?

Comment: Thank you for that I will definitely look into that Jiggles32. What I am trying to achieve ultimately is all records from Table 1 where at least one record from the group of records (each group is made up of records with the same ID) has a "Last Updated" Between April 1 and May 1, the second criteria is the ID

Comment: Create a query that has the `ID`s that you want to include. Then create a second query using `IN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not specify what operation you are trying to do but this will give you all the records from `Table1` that match your criteria.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT ID FROM Table1 
  WHERE [Last Updated Date] >=#4/1/2018 4:00:00 AM# 
  And [Last Updated Date] <=#5/1/2018 4:00:00 AM# )
```

Comment: So simple I'm sorry I had trouble articulating my problem but this definitely solved it. Thanks a lot!